# Programmatically changing the identifier property of UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

Through Interface Builder I have the ability to change the Identifier of a UIBarButtonItem to something like "Add" (or "Undo", "Redo" etc...). This gives my button a nice "+" image.

How can I set this programatically? The UIBarButtonItem does not accept a "setIdentifier" message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once constructed, a UIBarButtonItem's "Identifier" can not be modified. However, the UI can be changed by replacing the button with a programmatically constructed variant.  For example:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                                                                           target:self 
                                                                           action:@selector(doAddAction:)];
```

Comment: Your title for this post is misleading. This doesn't change the identifier of a UIBarButtonItem, it just creates a new one with the identifier property initialized. I'm looking for a way to modify the identifier on an existing button. A better title would be "Setting the identifier property of a newly created UIBarButtonItem programatically" or something similar.

Comment: I'm sorry you stumbled upon my solution and it didn't quite meet your expectations. At the point of asking the question I was looking for a way to, in fact, change it. The solution worked for me - if it didn't for you then I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If you want one button style: bordered and identifier: camera use

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn;
btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:@selector(shotAction:)];
btn.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the UIBarButtonItem is created, there is no way to change the identifier. However, you can create a new UIBarButtonItem to replace the old UIBarButtonItem

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(buttonClickedAction:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```